# Get Day, Month, Year separately from mysql in mktime format

Tags: php, mysql, date, mktime

I have a mktime code for adding date into database. This code display current date separately in mktime format.

```
<?php function drawDateTimePicker() { ?>
<select name="day">
    <?php for($x=1;$x<=31;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("j") == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<select name="month">
    <?php for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("n") == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$x)) ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<select name="year">
    <?php for($x=2009;$x<=2015;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("Y") == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>      
</select> / 
<select name="hour">
    <?php for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("H") == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

This code insert date into database field $row['birthdate']

I want to show date form $row['birthdate'] data when modify page.
in this code every time show current date, not match data in database

How can I retrieve data  from database and show it in modify page?

Thanks

RESOLUTION IS

```
<?php function drawDateTimePicker($mktimedata) { ?>

<select name="day">

    <?php for($x=1;$x<=31;$x++) { ?>

        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("j",$mktimedata) == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>    

    <?php } ?>

</select>

<select name="month">

    <?php for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++) { ?>

        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("n",$mktimedata) == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$x)) ?></option>    

    <?php } ?>

</select>

<select name="year">

    <?php for($x=2009;$x<=2015;$x++) { ?>

        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("Y",$mktimedata) == $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>    

    <?php } ?>        

</select>
```

drawDateTimePicker($date_in_database);

Comment: SELECT date .. from .... ? not really sure what you are asking, and what the above is to do with the retrieval from a db

Comment: For example, my birth date entered like 943912800 in mktime format in database. I will use this function for enter (or edit) birth date. But when I call the function, it gives today's date. I want to show birth day which is in the database. Look at selected fields. I want to be selected is data in my database

Comment: @Seyhan why do you store birth DATE in a time format? For compatibility with previous data?

Answer (score 0):

date([format]) gives you the actually Date. If you want a future or past Date you can do it with date([format], "time() of past Date"); for example:

```
date("Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 32, 1997));
```

To splitt the Date from Databse you can use something like:

```
$mydate = explode("-", $row["birthdate"]);
date("Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mydate[1], $mydate[2], $mydate[0]);
```

More examples on: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php

Or you split it with MySQL:

```
select YEAR(birthday) as y, MONTH(birthday) as m, DAY(birthday) as d FROM table
```

and use
$row["y"], $row["m"] and $row["d"]

```
<select name="day">
    <?php for($x=1;$x<=31;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= (date("j", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mydate[1], $mydate[2], $mydate[0]) == $x) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select name="day">
    <?php for($x=1;$x<=31;$x++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $x ?>"<?= ($row["d"] == $x) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?= $x ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi,I tried option one but it gives error message "Warning: mktime() expects parameter 6 to be long, string given in" and data in birthday field is 943912800 for date info

Comment: How is looking your input date? With format "Y-m-d", my examples works on my testserver.

Comment: I'm query my date like <?php $mt=$row['birthdate']; echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$mt); ?> end it gives me a  full date.

Comment: then you already save the integer value in seconds into your database? Then whats the problem?

Comment: Edit for example: date("n") == $x to date("n", $mt) == $x

Comment: Then real date is  29 11 1999 in database but output shown like 1 01 1970

Comment: Please give me an example value of your birthday column.

Comment: 943912800 this is the value in birthday field. it's defined as integer and corresponds to 29/11/1999

Comment: If that integer is represented by $mt, the output is:
$mt = 943912800;
print_r(date("Y", $mt)); // prints 1999
print_r(date("d", $mt)); // prints 29
print_r(date("m", $mt)); // prints 11
Check the date function manual on php.net

Comment: Yes I check it like you, it looks good, but date("n", $mt) == $x is not working

Comment: On my systems it works also with date("n", $mt) == $x. SO dont know whats wrong on your code.

Comment: The new question about this issue is;
How can I merge this separated dates parts and add into database one field